# How to get data from Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic?

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-galaxy-watch-4, samsung-health, google-health

I want to get data from Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 Classic, I used developer.samsung.com but unfortunately there is no helpful document and it navigates to google health service,Even though I can get heart rate by google health service but that did not get body composition and valid steps from this device.
I have another question, Is it possible to use samsung-health-data-a.b.c.aar in my android app to get data from this device?